# Adding text to collapsible d3 tree links

Tags: d3.js

I'm following this example here: https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/43a860bc0024792f8803bba8ca0d5ecd

On this part, I have:

```
  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  var linkEnter = link.enter().insert('path', "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .text(function(d) {
          console.log(d.data.expression);
          return d.data.expression;
      })
      .attr('d', function(d){
        var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0}
        return diagonal(o, o)
      });
```

I see the output to the console, but I don't see the text visibly on the link.

Below is the whole update() method.

```
function update(source) {

  // Assigns the x and y position for the nodes
  var treeData = treemap(root);

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = treeData.descendants(),
      links = treeData.descendants().slice(1);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d){ d.y = d.depth * 180});

  // ****************** Nodes section ***************************

  // Update the nodes...
  var node = svg.selectAll('g.node')
      .data(nodes, function(d) {return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  // Enter any new modes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append('g')
      .attr('class', 'node')
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
    })
    .on('click', click);

  // Add Circle for the nodes
  nodeEnter.append('circle')
      .attr('class', 'node')
      .attr('r', 1e-6)
      .style("fill", function(d) {
          return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
      });

  // Add labels for the nodes
  nodeEnter.append('text')
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("x", function(d) {
          return d.children || d._children ? -13 : 13;
      })
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
          return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
      })
      .text(function(d) { return "expression: " + d.data.expression; });

  // UPDATE
  var nodeUpdate = nodeEnter.merge(node);

  // Transition to the proper position for the node
  nodeUpdate.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
     });

  // Update the node attributes and style
  nodeUpdate.select('circle.node')
    .attr('r', 10)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
        return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
    })
    .attr('cursor', 'pointer');


  // Remove any exiting nodes
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
      })
      .remove();

  // On exit reduce the node circles size to 0
  nodeExit.select('circle')
    .attr('r', 1e-6);

  // On exit reduce the opacity of text labels
  nodeExit.select('text')
    .style('fill-opacity', 1e-6);

  // ****************** links section ***************************

  // Update the links...
  var link = svg.selectAll('path.link')
      .data(links, function(d) { return d.id; });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  var linkEnter = link.enter().insert('path', "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .text(function(d) {
          console.log(d.data.expression);
           return d.data.expression;
      })
      .attr('d', function(d){
        var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0}
        return diagonal(o, o)
      });

  // UPDATE
  var linkUpdate = linkEnter.merge(link);

  // Transition back to the parent element position
  linkUpdate.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr('d', function(d){ return diagonal(d, d.parent) });

  // Remove any exiting links
  var linkExit = link.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr('d', function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y}
        return diagonal(o, o)
      })
      .remove();

  // Store the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d){
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });

  // Creates a curved (diagonal) path from parent to the child nodes
  function diagonal(s, d) {

    path = `M ${s.y} ${s.x}
            C ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${s.x},
              ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${d.x},
              ${d.y} ${d.x}`

    return path
  }

  // Toggle children on click.
  function click(d) {
    if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d.children = null;
      } else {
        d.children = d._children;
        d._children = null;
      }
    update(d);
  }
}
```

If anyone can shed some light, I appreciate it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not very clear what you want to achieve with this line, but here is the problem:

After the insert...

```
var linkEnter = link.enter().insert('path', "g")
```

... this selection is a `<path>` selection. And, of course, there is no point in setting the `text` attribute of a path (which has none).

Whatever you want, break the block in two selections:

```
var linkEnter = link.enter().insert('path', "g")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr('d', function(d) {
        var o = {
            x: source.x0,
            y: source.y0
        }
        return diagonal(o, o)
    });

var fooEnter = link.enter().insert('text', "g")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .text(function(d) {
        console.log(d.data.expression);
        return d.data.expression;
    });
```

Comment: Thank you. This makes sense.